# TCPDUMP install problems

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, tcpdump

I'm getting an error when running the following command:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/tcpdump*
```

Which provides the following error:

> Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/bin/tcpdump' (Invalid argument)
>       The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file

As of yet I haven't been able to find any solutions - and would be extremely grateful to anyone who could offer or help me find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [base Debian package for `tcpdump`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/tcpdump/filelist), [as does the Ubuntu one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/tcpdump/filelist), shows the executable actually resides in **`/usr/sbin/tcpdump`**, and not `/usr/bin/tcpdump`.